# WCF - Webhttpbinding, see significant difference between PerCall and PerSession

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, webhttpbinding, instancecontextmode

I have tried to configure my wcf webhttpbinding (restful) service both PerSession and PerCall.

As far as I understand webhttpbinding does NOT use sessions to satisfy the restful principles, however I see significant performance differences when putting load on my service from LoadUI.

Shouldn't Persession and PerCall act the same way, since for every call a new Service Instance is created, because there are no sessions in webhttpbinding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The REST services architecture is stateless see ([REST WS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Constraints)) so it makes no sense to have the a rest service with

```
InstanceContextMode = PerSession.
```

The performance improvement using `PerSession` (however concurrency issues may appear) is for 
SOAP web-services.

Answering your question I believe that is a *fortunate series of events* (db connection pooling, database cache, etc) that you see a performance improvement.

As `InstanceContextMode.PerCall` is the stateless mode for WCF it is also instantiation mode of your rest service, even if you specified the `PerSession` as `InstanceContextMode`.